# Can't open, save jpg or png using Glimpse editor (Gimp fork) appimage

Tags: gimp

I'm using [the Glimpse fork](https://github.com/glimpse-editor/Glimpse/releases/tag/continuous) of GIMP, because the UI is nicer, and the name 'Gimp' reminds me of that scene from Pulp Fiction. Also I'm tired of looking at that Gimp mascot. Anyway, I can't open jpg or png files, or export in this format. When I try to open an image file, it says 'Unknown file type'. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to determine the exact issue here, but from the judge of it it seems like you either don't have permissions of that folder where you want to save the files, you are not specifying a correct file extensions when saving or both.

If you need to enable read,write and execute permissions to the folder where you want to save the files, you can use your terminal to do that. The command you will need is chmod and what value you will need for it is 750 so the command would be `chmod -R 750 /nameoffolder` which you will run in the parent folder to it.

As for the file extensions while saving issue, just double check you are adding the correct file extensions after the name of the file when you are saving it to the folder. For example .png or .jpg and so on.

Best of luck!